# Can I install MVC 3 into a windows container during the Docker build?

Tags: docker, asp.net-mvc-3, dockerfile, windows-container

I am attempting to "Lift and Shift" a legacy web service (and the website used to administer it) that was written using MVC 3.  I have used the visual studio "add -> docker support" feature and I am getting my website in a container and the website will run properly if I manually connect to the running container and install MVC 3.  I would much rather have MVC 3 installed when the container is built.

The dockerfile looks like this:

```
# escape=` (backtick)

FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
RUN  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe /q
```

The last line of the dockerfile is the thing that does not work.  I have tried several variations but the result is always some type of path not found error.

Examples of other attempted syntax:

```
RUN ["C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe", "/q"]
RUN ["powershell.exe", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe", "/q"]
RUN ["powershell.exe", ".\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe", "/q"]
RUN [".\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe", "/q"]
RUN AspNetMVC3Setup.exe /q
```

The paths and file names are correct when I connect to the running container but is it possible that during the build the files aren't really there yet?

How might I run the MVC install as part of the container build?

Error examples:

```
13>Step 5/5 : RUN  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe /q
13> ---> Running in 3b7e8c30f2e0
13>[91mC:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe : The term
13>[0m[91m'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe' is not recognized as the name of a
13>cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
13>[0m[91mname, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
13>[0m[91mAt line:1 char:76
13>[0m[91m+ ... rence = 'SilentlyContinue'; C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe /q
13>[0m[91m+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
13>    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Se
13>   tup.exe:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
13>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


13>Step 5/5 : RUN ["C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe", "/q"]
13> ---> Running in 7322410daf93
13>[91mAt line:1 char:77
13>[0m[91m+ ... ference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; [C:\inetp ...
13>+                                                                  ~
13>[0m[91mMissing ] at end of attribute or type literal.
13>[0m[91mAt line:1 char:78
13>+ ... ce = 'SilentlyContinue'; [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe, /q]
13>[0m[91m+                                
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
13>Unexpected token ':\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe' in expression or
13>[0m[91mstatement.
13>At line:1 char:115
13>+ ... ce = 'SilentlyContinue'; [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe, /q]
13>+                                                                     ~
13>Missing argument in parameter list.
13>    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
13>   ception
13>[0m[91m    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EndSquareBracketExpectedAtEndOfAttribute
13>
13>Service 'adminmanagement' failed to build: The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; ["C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe", "/q"]' returned a non-zero code: 1
13>[0m


13>Step 5/5 : RUN ["powershell.exe", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe", "/q"]
13> ---> Running in 44113a1005d2
13>[91mUnable to find type [powershell.exe,C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe,
13>/q]. Details: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from
13>HRESULT: 0x80131047)
13>At line:1 char:76
13>[0m[91m+ ... yContinue'; [powershell.exe, C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe,  ...
13>[0m[91m+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
13>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (powershell.exe,...C3Setup.exe
13>   , /q:TypeName) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
13>[0m[91m    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFoundWithMessage
13>[0m[91m
13>Service 'adminmanagement' failed to build: The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; ["powershell.exe", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe", "/q"]' returned a non-zero code: 1
 13>[0m
```

Comment: what output do you get for `Run` statement during build?

Comment: Could the ` (backtick) attribute be failing?  Possibly the \'s are being treated as escape characters?

Comment: Where is in your dockerfile are you adding this executable to image?

Comment: The exe was added to the project and is copied to the output, so the COPY line is taking care of that.  The file is there when I connect to the running container.  I'd be happy to change this, but attempts at copying that file separately to be 100% sure it was already there have resulted in equally problematic errors.  Since I used the visual studio feature, docker is now using strange temp folders and the paths don't make sense to me (they don't seem relative to the location of the dockerfile).

Comment: I suggest write a clean docker file without VS mumbo jumbo. VS is Frontpage of modern age where they try to simplify things but instead create a monster

Comment: Yeah, I had tried to do that, but can't seem to get that working (it worked a few days ago).  I'm wondering if VS changed the way docker is behaving.  As an example, this worked before and no longer works now: COPY ./bin/Release/PublishOutput/ /inetpub/wwwroot (instead of the $(varable) stuff).

Comment: This has given me the motivation to try getting the non-VS way to function again.  I'll try some things like removing and re-installing docker and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think it's docker config related, just crap that VS put in

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work within Visual Studio but by using a very similar dockerfile, a change to the .dockerignore and by invoking docker directly from PowerShell, I was able to have MVC 3 installed during the container build.

Dockerfile:

```
# escape=` (backtick)

FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
COPY ./bin/Release/Publish/ /inetpub/wwwroot
RUN C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe /q
```

.dockerignore file:

```
*
!./bin/Release/Publish/*
!obj\Docker\publish\*
!obj\Docker\empty\
```

The change to the .dockerignore was to add the following:

```
!./bin/Release/Publish/*
```

Docker commands:

```
docker build -t [imagename] .
docker run -d --name [containername] [imagename]
```